# what's wrong with my rock paper scissors?

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a javascript rock paper scissors application, but I've never written an application before. Can anyone help me out? For Rock, it always outputs a draw,
for Paper, it always outputs a loss,
for Scissors, it always outputs a win.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
var Rock;
var Paper;
var Scissors;
var choice = prompt("Specify your choice of 'Rock', 'Paper', or 'Scissors'.");
var game = [Rock, Paper, Scissors];

document.write("Rock.");
document.write("Paper..");
document.write("Scissors...");

var result = game[Math.floor(Math.random() * game.length)];

if (result === Rock) {
if (choice === "Rock") {
document.write("It's a draw! Try again.");
}
else if (choice === "Paper") {
document.write("You lose! Unlucky.");
}
else if (choice === "Scissors") {
document.write("You win! Nice.");
}}

else if (result === Paper) {
if (choice === "Rock") {
document.write("You win! Nice.");
}
else if (choice === "Paper") {
document.write("It's a draw! Try again.");
}
else if (choice === "Scissors") {
document.write("You lose! Unlucky.");
}}

else if (result === Scissors) {
if (choice === "Rock") {
document.write("You lose! Unlucky.");
}
else if (choice === "Paper") {
document.write("You win! Nice.");
}
else if (choice === "Scissors") {
document.write("It's a draw! Try again.");
}}
</script>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Rock`, `Paper` and `Scissors` are all `undefined`, so they'll always be equal. Set them to anything and it should work.

```
var Rock = 'Rock';
var Paper = 'Paper';
var Scissors = 'Scissors';
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `game` array is actually an array of 3 equal values: `var Rock` is the same as `var Paper` and `var Scissors`: they're all undefined, i.e. have no value.

If you just assigned a value to each of them, say `var Rock=1`, `var Paper=2` and `var Scissors=3`, your program should work. Having said that, you might as well just be using strings here, and you array should just be `["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"]`. You would then just test against the strings again, as you are with your `choice` variable.

edit:

Just for fun, here's what I meant in the comment below about things being easier with numbers:

```
var words = ['rock', 'paper', 'scissors'];
var played = words.indexOf( choice );
// if played is -1 here, your player typed in something other than the 3 words you accept

var result = Math.floor(Math.random() * game.length);
var outcome = ( played - result + 2 ) % 3;
var message
if ( outcome == 2 ) {
   message = "It's a draw! Try again.";
} else if ( outcome == 1 ) {
   message = "You lose! Unlucky.";
} else {
   message = "You win! Nice." );
}
document.write( message );
```

Comment: It's better to use 'array of strings' way, and not numbers, as long as we expect user to enter the whole string in prompt.

Comment: Well, sorta. If I had to write the above logic, I'd reverse that statement: the logic would be much simpler if we dealt with numbers.

Answer (score 1):

In short, it's because you're mixing string literals and unassigned variables in your application. It's rather simple to fix: put quotes around your Rock, Paper and Scissors, like that:

```
var game = ['Rock', 'Paper', 'Scissors'];
```

... and get rid of variables totally, as they're not needed. )

What's going on is:

1) you declare three variables - Rock, Paper and Scissors, but do not assign any value to them, so they stay `undefined`. Then you make an array from their values - essentially, an array of three identical elements, undefined.

2) then you try to generate some random value, but end up with `undefined`, as there nothing other in that array. So your `result` is *always* `undefined`.

3) then the first `if` check succeeds, because `undefined` (result) is strictly equal to `undefined` (Rock). Now the result is obvious: "Paper" (a string) wins, "Scissors" (again, a string) loses, and 'Rock' (did I mention that's a string too?) draws.

The final edit: do not ever confuse `undefined` with `'undefined'` (string). These are different too: former is falsy, for example, while latter is not.